# Multiple selection on TileList (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

Hey guys i have created the drawing application along with the layers.

For the layers panel i am using the tileList. And i have given the multiple selection option on the canvas. so the matter is that i want to make multiple selection on the TileList.

Can anyone suggest me or get some solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

property **`allowMultipleSelection`** set true. you possible using a ctrl + mouseClick or shift + mouseClcik multiple selection. And using **`selectedIndices`** can get a list of the selected.